# dynamic linq queries in linq-to-entities

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

what I want is to include 3 tables in my query and select only the last table fields.

```
[WebMethod]
public Project[] GetAlll(int passeid)//passed id is the id of fieldteammeber table I am passing
{
    var arr = db.Project.Include("FieldTeamMember")
                        .Include("FieldTeam")
                        .Where(ft_id=ftm_id and ft_mid=prj_ftm_id and FTM_ID=passeid)
                        .ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

want to select the project table fields. there are F keys between tables in the model.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting errors? Not the expected results?

Comment: it is just a mock up i just write it, I dont know if it is the correct syntax, it is not running.

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Can you write out a psuedo-query?

Comment: here is what I want. I have three table in my database, FieldTeamMember,FieldTeam and Projects. they are connected with Forign keys, Project has the ID of fieldteam, FieldteamMember has the Id of FieldTeam. I want to pass ID of FildTeamMember and get the list of Projects for that ID.

Comment: something like this in SQL select * from FIELD_TEAM f, FIELD_TEAM_MEMBER fm,PROJECT p
where f.FT_ID = fm.FTM_FT_ID and 
p.PRJ_FT_ID=f.FT_ID and
FTM_ID='24352345'

Comment: ignoring the columns for the filedTeam and FieldTeamMemeber tables in result set.

Comment: hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the query you're looking for based on your description:

```
int memberId = 1;
var projects = db.Projects
                 .Where(p => p.FieldTeam
                              .FieldTeamMembers.Any(ftm => ftm.Id == memberId));
```

Alternatively, if this is more readable to you:

```
int fieldTeamMemberId = 1;
var projects = db.FieldTeamMembers.Where(ftm => ftm.Id == memberId)
                                  .Select(ftm => ftm.FieldTeam.Project)
                                  .Distinct();
```

Comment: Now I am doing this way looks good but i get an error  [WebMethod]
        public Project[] GetAlll(String devid)
        {

            
            var pro = db.FieldTeamMembers.Where(ft => ft.FtmDeviceId == devid)
                                              .Select(ftm => ftm.FieldTeam.Project)
                                              .Distinct().ToArray();

            return pro;
        }

Comment: <system .collections.generic.icollection.project> [] to <system .collections.generic.icollection.project[]>

Comment: looks good now, I changed select to SelectMany and it worked. Looks a bit slow but I will find away around. thank buddy. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jaan: Is the FieldTeam -> Project relationship 1-to-Many? If so, using `SelectMany` is likely causing it to run a query for every `FieldTeamMember` in the table which could be causing the poor performance.

Comment: Yeha, I noticed that now. it is 1-Many.

Comment: there a problem that when I join more table to it, it work ok but if the columns in the table I am selecting from is null it is not showing the column in all but if I update that to value it starts showing up. it is the same for all column no mater their primary int or varchar but it only work for timestamp= null